# Moveit Tutorials step: Move_group interface Tutorial

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, move-group, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not go forward in this step of the tutorial, after opening Rviz the tutorial says to insert the command:

```
roslaunch moveit_tutorials move_group_interface_tutorial.launch
```

Then the following message appears:

```
[Move_group_interface_tutorial.launch] is not a launch file in package [moveit_tutorials] nor is [moveit_tutorials] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Can anybody help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254287/moveit-tutorials-step:-move_group-interface-tutorial/) by [Thadeu Brito](https://answers.ros.org/users/29268/thadeu-brito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! you missplelled the package name. The comand should be this:  `roslaunch pr2_moveit_tutorials move_group_interface_tutorial.launch`.

Edit:
I found out that the pr2_moveit_tutorials is outdated.
Try to update the moveit, because they update recently. Write on the terminal: `sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-moveit`. After that you should be able to follow the tutorial without problems.

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thadeu Brito](https://answers.ros.org/users/29268/thadeu-brito/) on 2017-02-18**:
Thanks! This helped me.
But now my screen is different of the tutorial page.In tutorial says: Should appears a option to press "Next" button. I don't see this in my screen, I tried add some panels, I didn't succeed.
Can you help me one more time?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-02-18**:
This answer is wrong (outdated).
The `pr2_moveit_tutorials` where recently merged into the `moveit_tutorials` repository and are in a subfolder [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/tree/kinetic-devel/doc/pr2_tutorials).

The roslaunch command given in the question works over here.